# which jar be responsible for parsing hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hsqldb

I met a configuration problem like below:
when I am executing example by [hibernate tool](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html) 
After I have write

> `<session-factory>`
>
> ```
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
>     <property name="connection.password"></property>
>     <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
>     <property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
>     <property name="show_sql">true</property>
>     <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
>     <mapping?resource="com/vaannila/course/Course.hbm.xml"/>
> ```
>
> <`session-factory>`

and open HSQLDB connection(using  `java -cp ./lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server` and `java -cp ./lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager`), when I use `Hibernate Code Generation` in  Eclipse, why it pop up the error message: 
[image]

In former step for the jar, instead of using package `slf4j*` ,I have used  `log4j`, and I remember I have not include the changed jar to my classpath as [vannilla required](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html), do it have affects for the error? thanks first :)

Comment: Maybe because you have <property?name instead of <property name and <mapping?resource instead of <mapping resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hibernate3.jar is responsible for parsing hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
      <property? //wrong
      <property> //correct
```

Comment: Friend, it's by the mistake when I print it into stackoverflow. the working hibernate.cfb.xml have note the `?` token, but still can not work.

Answer (score 1):

Those question marks in `<property?name..` are wrong - they should not be there. Remove them and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If the ? characters aren't visible in your editor, they are probably some other unicode space character which the XML parser doesn't recognise. You'll have to select each one and re-type a space character. (&nbsp; maybe?). Did you copy an example configuration from a web page?